# How do I fetch an endpoint on interval, stop the interval, and abort the call on leaving page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript

I am fetching messages every second after the previous call was successful.
The problem is, sometimes **it takes 2 seconds for the call to finish**. During that time, I can navigate back, choose another person and open the conversation with him.

Now, the **previous** **call** is successful and populates the area with **both** conversation data from UserA, and UserB. Furthermore, **it continuously fetches the conversations for both** UserA, and UserB.

I am suspecting that perhaps I should use `clearTimeout(interval)` instead of `clearTimeout(fetchConversationInterval)`, or use better code?

But also, how can I **abort** the still unfinished call if the user navigates back while the messages are being fetched?

I have the following code:

In data()

```
fetchConversationInterval: null,
```

On mounted():

```
this.messagesFetchingInterval()
```

And on beforeDestroy()

```
clearTimeout(this.fetchConversationInterval)
```

In methods:

```
async messagesFetchingInterval () {
  let that = this
  this.fetchConversationInterval = setTimeout(async function interval () {
    await that.getConversation(that.peerProfile.user_id)
      .finally(()=> {
        if (that.currentRoute === '/direct-messages/conversation') {
          that.fetchConversationInterval = setTimeout(interval, 1000)
        }
      })
  }, 1000)
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Async functions (in your case - getConversation) returns their subscription. you can save it in a parameter and then unsubscribe it in on destroy.

```
var mySubscription;

this.mySubscription = someAsyncFunc().subscribe((result) => {
   console.log(result);
})

ngOnDestroy(){
   this.mySubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```